# How to run my looping Bash script as a service?

Tags: linux, bash, amazon-ec2

I have 2 Amazon Linux EC2 instances that are running HAProxy. I want to monitor each instance from the other instance and if a instance becomes unavailable, the other instance will issue a API command to move the elastic IP to the active server.

I created a Bash script to do the monitoring every XX seconds. I need to set the script to run as a service so I created a service wrapper and placed in /etc/init.d based on a template that I found and registered as a service.

The problem is when I issue command #service hamonitor start, it says "Starting hamonitor...", but I never see the OK message and if I issue the stop command, it fails and if I issue the status command, it says it is not running. But, if I check the logs, it shows that the script is in fact running. I assume that I need a proper PID file and/or since the script runs in a infinite loop, it never completes so the OK does not get issued.

Service Wrapper:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# /etc/init.d/hamonitor
# Subsystem file for "hamonitor" server
#
# chkconfig: 2345 95 05 (1)
# description: hamonitor server daemon
#
# processname: hamonitor

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides: 
# Required-Start: 
# Required-Stop: 
# Should-Start: 
# Should-Stop: 
# Default-Start: 
# Default-Stop: 
# Short-Description: 
# Description:      
### END INIT INFO

# source function library
. /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions

PROG=hamonitor
EXEC=/etc/haproxy/hamonitor
LOCKFILE=/var/lock/subsys/$prog
PIDFILE=/var/run/$prog.pid
RETVAL=0

start() {
    echo -n $"Starting $PROG:"
    echo
    #daemon $EXEC &
    /etc/haproxy/hamonitor &
    RETVAL=$?
    if [ $RETVAL -eq 0 ]; then
      touch LOCKFILE
      touch PIDFILE
      echo "[ OK ]"
    else
      echo "[ FAIL: ${retval} ]"
    fi
    return $RETVAL
}

stop() {
    echo -n $"Stopping $PROG:"
    echo 
    killproc $PROG -TERM
    RETVAL=$?
    if [ $RETVAL -eq 0 ]; then
      rm -f LOCKFILE
      rm -f PIDFILE
      echo "[ OK ]"
    else
      echo "[ FAIL: ${RETVAL} ]"
    fi
    return $RETVAL
}

case "$1" in
  start)
    start
    ;;
  stop)
    stop
    ;;
  status)
    status $PROG
        RETVAL=$?
    ;;
  restart)
    stop
    start
    ;;
  *)
    echo $"Usage: $0 {start|stop|status|restart}"
    RETVAL=1
esac

exit $RETVAL
```

App:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

export EC2_HOME=/opt/aws/apitools/ec2
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jre

AWS_ACCESS_KEY="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
AWS_SECRET_KEY="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
VIP1="1.2.3.4"
VIP1_ALLOCATIONID="eipalloc-XXXXXXX"
THIS_NODE_EC2_ID="i-XXXXXXX"
THIS_NODE_PRIVATE_IPADDRESS1="10.60.0.11" 
THIS_NODE_HEALTHCHECK_URL="http://10.60.0.10/haproxy?monitor"
OTHER_NODE_HEALTHCHECK_URL="http://10.60.49.50/haproxy?monitor"
CHECK_OTHER_INTERVAL=5
CHECK_OTHER_FAIL_COUNT=0
CHECK_OTHER_RUN_COUNT=0
AFTER_TAKEOVER_WAIT=30

function takeover_vips {
  /opt/aws/bin/ec2-associate-address -aws-access-key ${AWS_ACCESS_KEY} -aws-secret-key ${AWS_SECRET_KEY} -a ${VIP1_ALLOCATIONID} -i ${THIS_NODE_EC2_ID} -private-ip-address ${THIS_NODE_PRIVATE_IPADDRESS1} -allow-reassociation > /dev/null
}

function does_this_node_have_ips {
  is_active=$(/opt/aws/bin/ec2-describe-addresses -aws-access-key ${AWS_ACCESS_KEY} -aws-secret-key ${AWS_SECRET_KEY}  | grep ${VIP1} | grep ${THIS_NODE_EC2_ID})
  if [ "$is_active" = "" ]; then
    echo "no"
  else
    echo "yes"
  fi
}

function log_msg {
  msg=$1
  msg="$(date) -- ${msg}"
  echo ${msg} >> /var/log/hamonitorlog
}

while [ . ]; do
    healthcheck_response=$(curl -sL -w "%{http_code}" ${OTHER_NODE_HEALTHCHECK_URL} -o /dev/null) 
    if [ "$healthcheck_response" != "200" ]; then
        CHECK_OTHER_FAIL_COUNT=$((CHECK_OTHER_FAIL_COUNT+1))
        if [ "$CHECK_OTHER_FAIL_COUNT" -gt 2 ]; then
          takeover_vips
          CHECK_OTHER_FAIL_COUNT=0
          sleep ${AFTER_TAKEOVER_WAIT}
        fi
    sleep ${CHECK_OTHER_INTERVAL}
done
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some Linux distribution have [*up-start*](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/) and other [*init*](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?init+8); I assume you have `init`.  The [`chkconfig`](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/chkconfig8.html) is being used to maintain *symlinks*.  You should confirm the comment,

```
# chkconfig: 2345 95 05 (1)
```

is correct for your system.

As a guess, you need [`daemon`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/daemon.3.html) to be invoked via a script.  This may have been a script function in some `init` script library, like */etc/rc.d/init.d/functions*.  I would suggest that you use the `daemon()` function if it exists.  Either,

```
  daemon $EXEC &                                               #option1
  nohup /etc/haproxy/hamonitor < /dev/null > /dev/null 2>&1 &  #option2
  /etc/haproxy/hamonitor&                                      #option3, 2 lines.
  disown $!                                                    #...
```

This is related to SIGCHLD and process return status (see [`man wait`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/wait.2.html) for more).  As well, you may need to detach `hamonitor` from the controlling terminal.  You can use [`logger`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/logger.1.html) to send information to the system logs in this case; I guess the *App* script is the `hamonitor` code?  Just change `echo` to `logger`.

If the `hamonitor` needs *stdout*, *stdin*, and/or *stderr*, you may need to redirect to some other file if it requires it.  You might also consider running it via [`screen`](http://ss64.com/bash/screen.html) if this is the case.

**Edit:** The last option can be used to create a proper `PIDFILE`.  For instance,

```
  # !!! optional grabbing of lock here...
  /etc/haproxy/hamonitor &   # spawn in bg
  HA_PID=$!                  # record spawn pid
  echo $HA_PID > $PIDFILE    # record the PID to a file for `stop`.
  # !!! optional release of lock here...
  disown $HA_PID             # detach script from terminal.
```

Services should never use `echo` and the like; `logger` is the better option.  This is probably not your issue unless `hamonitor` tries to read from something.  Mainly the issue is that `start()` will wait for the `hamonitor` to finish if you don't `disown`, so the *rc* script's *start* will never finish.

Generically, you can look at */etc/rc.d/init.d/functions*, provide a link to your file, or provide your distribution and version (or at least *linux standard base* conformance which seems to define how this should work in its different versions).  The file can be different on each and every Linux.  You can look at this file yourself if you understand scripting to see what *environment* variables, files, etc are expected and what functions you use in this file.  For instance, `killproc` is most likely defined there.

Comment: So since the app is running a continuous loop and I am not actually using a proper PID File should not be causing any issues?

Comment: `LOCKFILE` and `PIDFILE` are just regular files; especially if you don't use any functions in */etc/rc.d/init.d/functions*; these functions might have an **API** that expects these files to be set.  See [LFS's init.d/functions](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/6.4/scripts/apds02.html); The `killproc()` wants the $PIDFILE set to kill something from your `start()`.  Your $PIDFILE should be `$!`.  See edit; but this isn't why your *start* fails.

Comment: Instead of `killproc()`, you can use `pkill` or `killall`, if you know they can work for your system/scripts.  Then you don't need the *PIDFILE*.  *LOCKFILE* is generally to prevent multiple simultaneous starts.

Comment: I definitely want to prevent duplicate starts

Comment: Look for [`flock`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/flock) in the */etc/rc.d/init.d/functions* used with [*/var/lock*](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/2.2/fhs-5.9.html); this should be used to prevent duplicate starts, kills, etc.  However, for thing run from `init`, this shouldn't be happening.  In a multi-user environment, people might do multiple `service stop`, `service start` from different shells.  Probably this is pedantic unless you want bullet proof.  It should **not** prevent starts all the time.